# Do not send email immediately in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

In Outlook (and many other email apps), when I create an email and click "Send", it will be placed in the "Outbox"; it will only be sent when I click "Send and Receive" (or similar).

In Thunderbird, when I create an email and click "Send", it is sent immediately. How can configure it to move to the outbox and wait for my instruction to send?